# Are Constructors not members of a class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

Are Constructors not members of a class? If they are, why cannot they be inherited?

[JLS 7.0 says that constructors are not members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2) and hence cannot be inherited. Is that true alone for Java or is it a general OOP paradigm?

Comment: Where does it say this?

Comment: Section 8.2, page 197 in the PDF version of JLS 7.0.

Comment: in c++ to inherit you must to set it as virtual, about java-idk

Comment: `super()` exists to call parent constructor for Java.

Comment: If you think about what a constructor is for, this makes perfectly sence. *Any* constructor of the parent class might not have enough arguments to create an instance of the child class. 

As every class is *extending* Object, that would mean, every class would at least inherit a constructor without parameters - which would be a bad design, because it would screw up the purpose of using constructors for MANDATORY Attributes of the resulting instance. What kind of purpose would `Uri uri = new Uri()` have?

Comment: If you think about it, a constructor is part of the class, but not the instance.

Comment: dognose & Christopher, it does sound reasonable for Constructors synthesized by the Compiler. But, why should not an explicitly defined Constructor considered a member of the instances?

Comment: @PankajDwivedi What would it mean to have a constructor part of an *instance*? Ctors are used to *create* instances.

Comment: Dave, you are right. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited for a good design reason. If they are inherited, then you'd have problems trying to hide them in the inherited class.

Consider this example:

```
class Plane{
    public Plane(int passengerCapacity, int cargoCapacity){...}
}
class F18 extends Plane{
    public F18(){
        super(0,0);
        ....
    }
}
```

Now, does the following constructor make sense?

```
Plane p = new F18(0,0);
```

Not really, because the child class is a special case of the parent class. In this particular example, it does not make sense to provide the Plane constructors in the F18 class; the child class wishes to control how the parent class is constructed.

If constructors are inherited and someone wish to hide the parent constructors, they may attempt to do something like this:

```
class F18{
    Plane innerPlane;
    public F18(){
        innerPlane = new Plane(0,0);
    }
}
```

Not really a solution because in every method and property, one would have to write `return innerPlane.SomeMethod();`, which pretty much defeats the purpose of inheritance.

This principals apply to other OOP languages (e.g. C#) as well.

**But what if I really want to inherit constructors in many child class...**

Then your architecture is wrong. You don't actually need inheritance to solve your problem. You can abstract the parts that are different in another base class / interface. e.g.

```
class Plane{
    IPilot Pilot;
    public Plane(int passengerCapacity, int cargoCapacity, IPilot pilot){...}
}
```

Constructors are ways to construct an object. Do you really need many child class which can be constructed in the same way (and using the same logic, since they're inherited), or a class which has the flexibility to swap out some of its components?

Comment: Might also want to add that `super()` works to call `default` and `private` constructors also, to "good design causes".

Comment: Thanks, kayson! The explanation is quite apt.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of inheriting a constructor does not make sense in most paradigms; instead the constructors are called in reverse order of inheritance, so for example if you have:

```
Pidgeon -> Bird -> Animal
```

Where `->` indicates 'inherits from', then to construct a `Pidgeon` it first calls the `Animal` constructor, then the `Bird` constructor and, finally, the `Pidgeon` constructor. If it didn't do it this way then you would have to either initialise all members of the class you're inheriting from or manually call the constructor of the base class (as you may have to do *anyway* if you have specific parameters to pass).

Or, to put in another, whereas normally a function in the derived class *replaces* the function in the base class, constructors *extend* the function in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Despite you may hear, this is not general OOP paradigm. I think, there are old OOP languages, where constructor was just normal method. But currently many popular languages treat constructors in different manner, as other methods. This is imperfect solution with leads to some workarounds, like recommendation in Beans specification to have only none-argument constructors.